# Is it possible to have a different 'views' of code with different coding styles?

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, ide

I'm looking for a method to easily switch between coding styles (specifically - indentation and line breaks)

This will allow different team members work with their preferred coding style - without effecting how other team members view the code.

a transparent method is best (that is - a file is saved always in the 'standard' style, but viewed and edited in the 'personal' style).

I'm interested mainly in eclipse, but other IDEs \ editors can also be relevant.